# React-native. How to check the user's Apple Store and the Play Market (Android) region country code

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I need to restrict content in a certain country, based user's country code(region) set in the Apple Store and Play Market (Android)?

How to check in react-native?

`getCountry()` method from `react-native-localize` gets region from (Ios): `settings > language & region > region`

but this is different. And the region in the settings is easy to change, unlike the region in Appstore.